# Create CAML SPQuery to order by ItemChildCount in descending order

Tags: caml-query, spquery

How do I create a CAML query to display all items on the list order by ItemChildCount?

Somewhat like this:

```
 Select * 
 from table 
 order by itemChildCount descending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [OrderBy Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467378.aspx) is what you're looking for:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ItemChildCount' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
```

Adapted from the example here: [SPQuery.ViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx)

Additionally, this is a useful CAML Query reference: [Query Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467521.aspx)

Comment: Still have problem on the query. I created another question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15312/problem-with-caml-spquery-itemchildcount-result

Answer (score 2):

Tools like [Strammit](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/) or [U2U](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) can help you build any CAML you desire.