# Problem with CAML SPQuery ItemChildCount result

Tags: caml-query, splistitem, spquery

I know that this query works fine

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ItemChildCount' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy>";
```

But my SPListItemCollection doesn't display what I'm expecting as a result.

```
Actual Dispaly in C#             Actual Display in CAML Query Builder

ID | Title | ItemChildCount|     ID | Title | ItemChildCount |
---|-------|---------------|     ---|-------|----------------|
11 | Abc   |    11;#5      |     11 | Abc   |       5        |
---|-------|---------------|     ---|-------|----------------|
22 | BBB   |    22;#9      |     22 | BBB   |       9        |
---|-------|---------------|     ---|-------|----------------|
24 | Cbc   |    24;#7      |     24 | Cbc   |       7        |
```

I wonder why in U2U CAML Query Builder, the sort by ItemChildCount doesn't work. 
I tried to sort the items by ItemChildCount yet it sorts the ID instead.

But, when I check on the result on C# code immediate window using SPListItem["ItemChildCount"] it displays the concatenated ID and the ItemChildCount resulting to something like this 11;#5.

How will I create a query where I can do some string manipulations on the CAML query.
Something like this

```
Select * from ListCollection Order by ItemChildCount.Replace("11;#","")
```

If ever this is possible.

Comment: it looks like you use the reverse lookup column ? in all case, can you show us the definition of your column ?

Comment: Please do not [crosspost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514911/create-caml-spquery-to-order-by-itemchildcount-in-descending-order) questions between sites. We should choose one question to keep and delete the other. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073

Comment: @Kit Menke:  Sorry my bad, I didn't know that it is against the rule :). I was just desperate to find the solution that I'm looking for. Already deleted my other post on stackoverflow. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to say it, but I'm afraid I don't think this is possible using CAML. Even joining the list to itself and using a `GroupBy` element wouldn't help because `GroupBy` isn't equivalent to its SQL counterpart.

My suggestion would be to:

- Query the Item ID and ItemChildCount from the list (unordered)
- Create a dictionary keyed by ItemChildCount (stripped), with the value being an array of item IDs that have that ItemChildCount
- Populate the dictionary with the queried data
- Work through the dictionary's keys in descending order, querying the Items in batches using the [In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx) CAML operator

Example of batch query:

```
<Where><In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values><Value Type="Number">1</Value><Value Type="Number">3</Value></Values></In></Where>
```

P.S. Trying to turn SQL into C# and CAML makes two very disconnected parts of my brain try to work together in a particularly nauseating way. Bleurgh.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 var field = ItemChildCount.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("ItemChildCount");     
 var actualCount = field.GetValueAsHtml(ItemChildCount[field.Id]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help with ordering the query results. :/

Comment: The real problem I have is sorting the ItemChildCount. Please refer to my previous issue http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15164/create-caml-spquery-to-order-by-itemchildcount-in-descending-order

Comment: depending on the number of items you want to retrieve, you can move to a coded orderby using a code similar to the one I provided. But this will be at performance cost, so don't use this if you have a large number of items (or cache the result at least). Don't know if it can be achieved using a pure caml query...

Comment: Yep I also doubt that this can be done using pure caml query. I'm also looking forward on solving this issue using camlex.net (http://camlex.codeplex.com/). The list I'm working on right now is definitely growing fast because it is a discussion list for the intranet so optimization is also part of my concern :)